# Trying to Create a remote login tool: "interact" in "expect << EOF" does not work

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

The use case of this script is I have various servers with different ssh keys. I am trying to write a script so when called will log into the specified server. An example of usage would be:

```
    ./ServerLogin.sh Server1
```

I feel that I am fairly close, but The last part of expect interact is tripping me up. This is a simplified version:

```
#!/bin/bash

ServerName="$1"
case $ServerName in 
  "Server1") IP="1.2.3.4" ; keyPath="/path/to/key.pem" ; password="password" ; break ;;
  *)         echo "Server not recognized" ; exit ;;
esac 

/usr/bin/expect << EOD
spawn ssh -i $keyPath user@$IP
expect "*.pem': "
send "$password\r"
interact
EOD
```

The result of this is it logs in and immediately closes. I want for the session to remain interactable.

Any ideas?

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp ...` and see whats happening.

Comment: Exactly as expected, it is logging in, reaching the interact and closing because the script is done. I don't want the script to end though... 
`interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0`

Comment: Why not use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`?

Comment: I suppose because I am not familiar enough with those tools. I did find a solution to the problem, so I will update with the answer below.

Comment: (or write the whole thing in tcl/expect instead of mixing and matching with shell) -- but anyways, looks a lot like something is making the ssh session exit. Adding full debug output to your question would be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `expect << EOF`. With `expect << EOF`, expect's stdin is the here-doc rather than a tty. But the `interact` command only works when expect's stdin is a tty. Your answer is one solution. Another solution is to use `expect -c` if you prefer not using a tmp file.

```
expect -c "
  spawn ssh -i $keyPath user@$IP
  expect \"*.pem': \"
  send \"$password\r\"
  interact
"
```

Comment: Excellent! this is the explanation I was looking for! I will likely be using this going forward because there's a bit more complexity to my bash script. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After toying around with it some more, I found a working solution. Basically create the expect script and run it. Why it works like this and not in the original question is beyond me. But it works and I will use this for the time being. Thanks everyone for the help!

Working Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

ServerName="$1"
case $ServerName in 
  "Server1") IP="1.2.3.4" ; keyPath="/path/to/key.pem" ; password="password" ; break ;;
  *)         echo "Server not recognized" ; exit ;;
esac 

function WriteExp {
  echo "#!/usr/bin/expect"
  echo "spawn ssh -i $keyPath ubuntu@$IP"
  echo "expect \"*.pem': \""
  echo "send \"$password\\r\""
  echo "interact"
}

WriteExp > $ServerName.exp
chmod 755 $ServerName.exp

/usr/bin/expect $ServerName.exp

# Cleanup the evidence
rm $ServerName.exp
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just tcl/expect, instead of a hybrid of shell and it, makes for much cleaner code, without any of the potential issues posed by shell variable interpolation:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

switch -- [lindex $argv 0] {
    Server1 { 
       set IP 1.2.3.4
       set keyPath /path/to/key.pem
       set password "password"
    }
    default {
       puts stderr "Server not recognized"
       exit 1
    }
}

spawn ssh -i $keyPath user@$IP
expect "*.pem': "
send "$password\r"
interact
```

Comment: Ah! I did google switch statements in expect yesterday and did not find a nice example. I'm glad to know this is possible in pure expect.